# Remove vertical space between columns with CSS - flex

Tags: css, flexbox

I want to create a grid with 2 columns using `flex` and that's what I have:

[image]

And this is my code:

```
.wrap-columns {
    display: flex;
    flew-wrap: wrap;
}
```

And I want to remove the vertical space between elements when right element is bigger than next left element, I want something like this:

[image]

Can I do that with flexbox??

Thanks!

Comment: _"Can I do that with flexbox??"_ - no.

Comment: Ok @CBroe, I will do it with float: left and right; - Thank you!

Comment: You can do it with flexbox you have to change your flex-drirection though